# How to ignore a handlebars expression in Mustache templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I've read over the Mustache specs on templating several times, but I can not figure out how to have a handlebars expression ignored. I have a mustache template that must render a `{{value}}` as shown, but mustache doesn't seem to have a way to escape the handlebars.

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

For example;

**example.mustache**

```html
<p>This would {{value}} not be changed</p>
```

I need the above `{{value}}` to be printed in the template output.

Here is a code snip demonstrating what I've tried.

```js
console.log(Mustache.render('Example of {{value}} what I want ignored',{}));
console.log(Mustache.render('Does not work \\{\\{value\\}\\}',{}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.3/mustache.js"></script>
```

I'm sure it's something stupidly simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a **crazy** long time to figure out the *official* way of escaping handlebars, and it was hidden in some source code comments.

```html
<p>This would {{ "{{" }}value{{ "}}" }} not be changed</p>
```

Needless to say there is no actual way to escape them. The *trick* is to just emit a string value of handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around for your requirement,

```
var dataObject ={}
dataObject.openbrace = '{{';
dataObject.closebrace = '}}';
dataObject.value = 'Your Value';

    console.log(Mustache.render('Example of {{value}} what I want ignored',{}));
    console.log(Mustache.render('Does not work {{openbrace}}{{value}}{{closebrace}}',dataObject ));
```

or You can  use some delimiter 
Mustache.render('Example of  {{=<% "{{" %>=}}{<% value %>}<%={{ "}}" }}=%>', routeObj);